# Magento 2 UI Grid - How to add tabs in columns control?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-grid

I want to add Tabs in Columns control of my custom extension’s UI Grid to categorize columns.

For Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>` under `<listingToolbar>` tag of your grid uicomponent xml file. If you do not have added `<listingToolbar>` tag then simply add the below code under `<listing>` tag of your grid xml.

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
     <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
</listingToolbar>
```

Hope it finds you helpful.

Comment: I have already added <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/> under <listingToolbar> tag of my grid uicomponent xml file. So I am able to see Columns control.
But now I want to categorize the list of columns with Tabs, as shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/7110B.png 
How can I achieve that?